# how to check if sort merge bucket join working or not in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to verify if my SMB join is working or not.I am able to verify map join through log but not SMB.I went through explain plan also but couldn't get any hint. Please help me.

Comment: "explain" will give details if SMB join is applied or not.

Comment: Could you tell what detail it gives to verify SMB?I mean what keyword? For ex. for Map join it writes Map Join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use EXPLAIN EXTENDED on the queries.
I've so far only been able to produce an SMB map join with map-reduce.
When hive is doing an SMB map join you can see "Sorted Merge Bucket Map Join Operator" under stage plans in the output of explain.

Here is a code snippet that produces an SMB map join with map-reduce on my setup:

```
set hive.execution.engine=mr;
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join=true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge=true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.enforce.sorting=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;

drop table key_value_large;
drop table key_value_small;

create table key_value_large  (
    key int,
    value string
)
partitioned by (ds string)
CLUSTERED BY (key) SORTED BY (key ASC) INTO 8 BUCKETS 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

create table key_value_small (
    key int,
    value string
)
partitioned by (ds string)
CLUSTERED BY (key) SORTED BY (key ASC) INTO 4 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE;


insert into table key_value_large partition(ds='2008-04-08') select key, value from key_value_large_src;
insert into table key_value_small partition(ds='2008-04-08') select key, value from key_value_small_src;

explain extended select count(*) from key_value_large a JOIN key_value_small b ON a.key = b.key;
select count(*) from key_value_large a JOIN key_value_small b ON a.key = b.key;
```

Hope that might help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the hint for SMBM join

```
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join=true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin = true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge = true;
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask=true;
```

After using the above hints. if you have to table which qualify for SMBM join(both tables should be bucketed  by same column and into same number of buckets and you must join the table using the bucketed column)

The EXPLAIN shows the below o/p for the join query

```
OK
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-1 is a root stage
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Map Operator Tree:
          TableScan
            alias: a
            Statistics: Num rows: 13 Data size: 1289 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            Sorted Merge Bucket Map Join Operator
              condition map:
                   Inner Join 0 to 1
              condition expressions:
                0 {realm} {role} {lid} {mid} {sid} {insert_date}
                1 {realm} {role} {lid} {mid} {sid} {insert_date}
              keys:
                0 mid (type: string)
                1 mid (type: string)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col8, _col9, _col10, _col11, _col12, _col13
              Select Operator
                expressions: _col0 (type: string), _col1 (type: string), _col2 (type: string), _col3 (type: string), _col4 (type: string), _col5 (type: date), _col8 (type: string), _col9 (type: string), _col10 (type: string), _col11 (type: string), _col12 (type: string), _col13 (type: date)
                outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7, _col8, _col9, _col10, _col11
                File Output Operator
                  compressed: true
                  table:
                      input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
                      output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
                      serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe

  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1

Time taken: 0.131 seconds, Fetched: 35 row(s)
```

As you can see the o/p clearly says that it will perform SMBM join.